# Faces of model exported from blender to three js made weird things

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I have a problem when I import my model from blender to three.js using three.js Json exporter.

So this is an exemple of my object in blender :

[My object in blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij3F4.png)

And this is what I have in my browser after the import :

https://gyazo.com/5310e934c30ebfc8300bb24cbf4a24eb

I have already try to flip normals without sucess…
This is how I import my model :

```
loadFile() {
if (this.index > this.files.length - 1) return
this.Loader.load(this.files[this.index], (geometry, materials)=>{
  geometry.computeFaceNormals()
  geometry.computeFlatVertexNormals()
  geometry.computeVertexNormals()
  for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) {
    // materials[i].morphTargets = true
    materials[i].side = THREE.DoubleSide
    // materials[i].transparent = true
  }

  let object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials)
  object.rotation.y = 90 * (Math.PI / 180)
  this.index++
  this.loadFile()
  this.markerRoot.add( object )
})
```

}

I have no idea why this is happening, if you have any idea I would be very grateful.

Comment: Looks like some [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). This might be because you're rendering the backside of the face also. Check [backface culling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/cullFace)

Comment: Your second image link does not load for me. This is why it's important to include all information in or embedded in the post. Please edit your post to insert the images, rather than linking them.

Comment: Did you tried changing `materials[i].side = THREE.DoubleSide` to `THREE.FrontSide` or `THREE.BackSide`? It seems that your model also have faces on the inside which are to close. (the object is not thick enough, so the faces on the inside are interfering.)